# 1 onTouchListener For many Buttons

Tags: android

Well I have onTouchListener method like this

```
public void imageclick(ImageView image) {
    image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {


                //To do! smthg break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                //To do! smthg break;

            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                //To do!
                break;
            }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I want to use this methods for my buttons but it is not working properly, It needs double or more touch to fire ACTION_UP event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `Activity` implement `View.OnTouchListener`, and for all your buttons call `button.setOnTouchListener(this)`.

Set for all your buttons different ids.
How to differ between buttons:

```
OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can understand which button touched